# Importing History from SVN to Git - Change Committer Information

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I'm working on converting some Subversion repositories over to Git using the git-svn tool.  I noticed that even though it imports the author information correctly, the committer information does not match the author information (e.g. the committer date is the date/time I ran the git-svn tool).

Is there a way to make the committer information match the author information on import from Subversion?  If not, how can I use git-filter-branch to rewrite the commits to correct this (i.e. copy author info into committer info for each commit)?

Thanks!

**---UPDATE---**

Git-svn is not causing this problem, I am!  I've been rebasing the Subversion history, and that is changing the committer date.  So, does any one how to use git-filter-branch to change this (i.e. copy author info into committer info for each commit)?

Comment: FWIW, I also use git-svn and it doesn't behave this way for me. The committer and author information always match.

Comment: I figured out what was happening - I've been rebasing the SVN history, and that is changing the committer date.

Comment: Since it is not a problem with git-svn, anyone know how to copy the author info into the committer info field using a filter-branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `--env-filter` mode of filter-branch.  The relevant environment variables are `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`, `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`, and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`.

Your command will be something like:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"' -- --all
```

The `--all` specifies that this should operate on all branches. Your original refs will be preserved in the refs/original namespace in case you mess up.

<sub>And of course, I can't post anything like this without a warning of the dangers for anyone who may happen upon it. From man git-filter-branch:</sub>

> WARNING! The rewritten history will have different object names for all the objects and will not converge with the original branch. You will not be able to easily push and distribute the rewritten branch on top of the original branch.  Please do not use this command if you do not know the full implications, and avoid using it anyway, if a simple single commit would suffice to fix your problem. (See the "RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE" section in git-rebase(1) for further information about rewriting published history.)

Comment: This was the correct answer, however there was a minor typo: you cannot put the '=' character after --env-filter; it must be a space.  Other than that it worked perfectly.  Thanks!